# Error in applying holo dark theme in android

Tags: android

I am trying to apply holo dark theme by using the following

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

in `values-v14` and `values` folder.

But when I apply it in manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
```

I still do not get the dark theme in my app.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what target version have you set in your project?

Comment: In which target(api level) are you running the app?